# Does adding [DataContract] and [DataMember] to all classes impact performance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datacontract

Lets say we got a code generating tool that creates thousands of C# classes, and we sometimes need to add those attributes to them.

We are considering whether it is better to put `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` on all appropriate classes or we need to create a special strategy that will determine whether to do so in order to save up some possible? performance lost in AtribbuteAll approach.

In the end the question is whether adding attributes can somehow affect performance?

I am thinking that adding an attribute on a class will simply stay with its type information and should not affect any performance but would like to be 100% certain here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding attributes would impact in performance if these are inspected in some part of the code, if not, classes would have more metadata, but this doesn't impact performance.

Answer (score 1):

Doubtful that this will affect performance, all these attributes do is mark them as serializable for WCF.

Answer (score 0):

impact performance is unavoidable.
but if you need attribute to complete your attention, you have not other choice.
if you do not need, you may remove it.